# Check if table cell has content and mark cell with symbol &#9700;

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to check if a table cell has a specific content and to mark that cell with the symbol " ◤ " in the top left corner of that cell?
Thanks

Comment: you could do a loop and check for the desired content, when you find it you just add that symbol to the content

Comment: somebody already posted a jquery solution, if you want to do it on the backend checkout this php function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php or you could even just use str_replace() http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Comment: if you are referring to the post that puts the triangle outside the table... i have already seen it. it's no good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a PHP solution.

Let's say you have a MySQL database you're connected to and the table has columns 'state_or_province', 'city', and 'country'.  If you want to mark all cells with the state or province value of "GA", you would use something like this:

```
echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myresults)){
    echo "<tr>";
            if($row["state_or_province"] == "GA"){
                echo "<td class = 'red'>".$row["state_or_province"]."</td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td>".$row["state_or_province"]."</td>";
            }
            echo "<td>".$row["city"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["country"]."</td>
                  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

In your CSS style section, include the following

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

In this example, all cells that have the value 'GA' under the 'State' column of our rendered table would appear in a red cell.  Just edit the above CSS if you want to have the "◤" symbol appear on the top left hand corner instead

**UPDATE**

Change

```
        if($row["state_or_province"] == "GA"){
            echo "<td class = 'red'>".$row["state_or_province"]."</td>";
        }
```

to

```
        if($row["state_or_province"] == "GA"){
            echo "<td class = 'red'>&#9700".$row["state_or_province"]."</td>";
        }
```

and you'll see the triangles inside the text boxes

Comment: Your idea is the closest that i wanted but it does not keep the ◤ symbol inside the table cell... it puts the symbol on top of page... any ideas?

Comment: thank you for your effort but i have used a background image on the affected TD. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

use this find and rerplace function:

```
  function ReplaceCellContent(find, replace)
    {
        $("#table tr td:contains('" + find + "')").html(replace);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to replace the content, just mark interesting cell with the "◤".

You can use CSS `:before` to do that

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ipsum</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("td:contains('ipsum')").addClass('found');
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3NWQD/1/

Comment: Yeah... that's right... in your example i want all the cells with ipsum marked with the triangle and also to keep the "ipsum". But the example that you provided puts the triangle outside the table cells...

Comment: i use Firefox... i can see now that IE and Chrome displays ok... but not Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Example JSFiddle answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ATV4G/1/

Javascript:

```
    function markCell(containingText, replaceWith) { //making our function
        $("td:contains('"+containingText+"')").prepend("<span class='abs'>"+replaceWith+"        </span>");
    }

    markCell("first", "◤"); //calling the function
```

CSS:

```
    .abs {
            position: absolute;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>first</td>
                <td>second</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

These are the minimum requirements. If you want to beautify the output, you can write further CSS to achieve requirements. (Please check JSFiddle example)

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="table">
    <tr><th>No</th><th>Player Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Sachin</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Dhoni</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Raina</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>Yuvi</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>Sachin</td></tr>
  </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
function MarkCell(PlayerName)
{
    $("td").each(function(){ 
        //alert($(this).text());
        if($(this).text() == PlayerName)
        {
            $(this).html('&#9700;' + PlayerName);
        }
    });
}

MarkCell('Sachin');
```

live fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LDFT2/)

Comment: that one is good also ... but the same problem appears... in firefox it does not work.

Comment: which version of Firefox are you using ? In Firefox version 19.0.2 it's just working fine.

Comment: As per wiki Firefox 19.0 is **Former release; no longer supported**, you should update your firefox. I've verified it in Version 18.0.2 and it's working fine.

Comment: I have solved the problem... but not changing firefox... i used background:url(); and i have used Lloyd Banks's idea. Thank you all.